# jQuery slider loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider

Hey I have a slider where a logo slides from the right to the left side.
Now I want it to start again from right to left (not going back from left to right!).

How do I do this?
I'm super new to jQuery

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>animate demo</title>
<style>
#background {
width:980px;
height:75px;
background-color:#abc;
}
#logo1 {
position:absolute;
width:234px;
height:40px;
margin:17px 0px 0px 700px;
background-image:url(bru.png);
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background">
<div id="logo1" class="right"></div>
<script>
$(".right").ready(function() {
$("#logo1").animate({"left":"-=600px"},10000);
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to keep appending new elements so it doesn't go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(".right").ready(function() {
        /* animation F definition*/
        var animate = function(cb){
            $("#logo1").animate({"left":"-=600px"}/*properties end values*/,
                                  1000 /* duration */,
                                  function()/* on complete F*/{
                                      this.style.left = 0; /* reset style properties */
                                          if(cb&&cb.call){
                                              cb(animate); /* call animation again */
                                          }
                                  })
        };
        /* First call */
        animate(animate);
    });
</script>
```

Simply define your animation function and call it in callback on animation complete. That will loop it.

Comment: Thanks this would be great, just that it goes waaaay to fast! How can I change the speed ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick stab at it, but something to this effect?

http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/CzyCr/

Use a relative position with the parent having a hidden overflow:

```
var loop = function(){
    $("#logo1").animate({"left":"-=1300px"},10000, function(){
        $('#logo1').css({'left':'1000px'});
        loop();
    });
};

loop();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to occur just once, place this after the first animate

**JAVASCRIPT: OCCUR ONCE**

```
$(".right").ready(function() {
    $("#logo1").animate({"left":"-=600px"}, 10000);
    $("#logo1").animate({"left":"+=600px"}, 10000);
});
```

If you want it to constantly loop...

**JAVASCRIPT: REPEAT**

```
$(".right").ready(function() {
    var left = function () {
        $("#logo1").animate({"left":"-=600px"}, 10000);
        right();
    }
    var right = function () {
        $("#logo1").animate({"left":"+=600px"}, 10000);
        left();
    }
    left();
});
```